# BSTR bstrRtf = 0xcccccccccccccccc <Bad Ptr> on debugging ( = CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated)

Tags: c++, xslt, xml-parsing, bstr, ixmldomdocument

I am using an IXLMDOMDocument to load a xml file from a stream using

```
IXMLDOMDocument *pDomDoc = pDomDoc->load(vtHtmlSource, &vfSuccess);
```

After loading the stream (containing the xml contents) it creates a style sheet in order to  get the content `ident` properly. The above part is working without any problem. I am sure about that but after that when A transform Node (stylesheet in to `bstrRtf`) by doing as below -

```
BSTR bstrRtf;
hr  = pDomDoc->transformNode(m_pStyleSheetNode, &bstrRtf);
//on debugging we get m_pStyleSheetNode = 0x0000000002b77ba8 that means it is correct and stylesheet is created properly.
//but bstrRtf = 0xcccccccccccccccc <Bad Ptr>  = CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated 
//that means there is some problem here

if (hr) {
    hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()); //this hr surprisingly returns OK(hr = S_OK)
};
```

I don't know why or how. It should not do so because in `bstrRtf` we have a very strange value. I expect it to give some error, but I don't know why it does so.

Could any one explain what it means by  `bstrRtf = 0xcccccccccccccccc <Bad Ptr>`? When would someone get this type of error? What is the meaning of `0xcccccccccccccccc <Bad Ptr>`?

when i intialize it with zero the error is `instance->m_bstrRtf = 0x0000000000000000 <Bad Ptr>` on debugging. and not working. but why it returns S_OK even after this??

Answer (score 2):

`bstrRtf` is not initialized - it has no valid value yet. The actual value of `0xcccccccccccccccc` is what MS fills the memory with so that it is possible to detect uninitalized variables.

This value is picked specifically so that it's "not a valid memory address" - that way, you can't accidentally or on purpose use the memory of an uninitialized variable without getting some sort of error or trap.

Comment: so you mean i just need to intialize it ??

Comment: when i intialize it with zero the  error is instance->m_bstrRtf = 0x0000000000000000 <Bad Ptr> on debugging. and not working. but why it returns S_OK even after this??

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. The documentation seems to imply that `pDomDoc->transformNode()` should fill in the `bstrRtf` with an allocation. But the fact that it doesn't change seems to indicate that it hasn't been changed.